# sharing objects between doctrine2 odm and orm in symfony2 with doctrine extensions

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions, stofdoctrineextensions

in my project i need to share objects between orm and odm. I have an entity "Variation" and a document "Tracking". One variation can hold many trackingevents. I tried to solve it through doctrine extension references using the stofdoctrineextensionbundle for symfony 2.3 but whatever i do it wont work. Maybe someone of you have an idea.

Tracking Document: ( watch for $variation )

```
namespace Anchorbrands\Bundle\LandingpageBundle\Document;

use Anchorbrands\Bundle\LandingpageBundle\AnchorbrandsLandingpageBundle;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;


/**
 * @ODM\Document(collection="landingpage_tracking")
 */
class Tracking {

    /**
     * @Gedmo\ReferenceOne(type="entity", class="Anchorbrands\Bundle\LandingpageBundle\Entity\Variation", inversedBy="trackingEvents", identifier="variationId")
     */
    protected $variation;

    protected $variationId;

    public function setVariationId($variationId)
    {
        $this->variationId = $variationId;
    }

    public function getVariationId()
    {
        return $this->variationId;
    }
```

Variation Entity ( watch out for $trackingEvents )

```
/**
 * Variation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="landingpage_variation")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Variation
{

/**
 * @Gedmo\ReferenceMany(type="document", class="Anchorbrands\Bundle\LandingpageBundle\Document\Tracking", mappedBy="variation")
 */
protected $trackingEvents;


public function getTrackingEvents()
{
    return $this->trackingEvents;
}

public function setTrackingEvents(Collection $trackingEvents)
{
    $this->trackingEvents = $trackingEvents;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by sharing the objects - what are you trying to achieve exactly? please fix the code in the question.

Comment: Hi, i want documents to be referenced to entities.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround to the circular referencing problem (unless you can solve it using DI) @see stof's bundle

```
<?php

namespace ACME\CoreBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * Class ReferencesListener
 *
 * @package ACME\CoreBundle\Listener
 */
class ReferencesListener extends \Gedmo\References\ReferencesListener
{
    /**
     * @var \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $managers
        = [
            'document' => 'doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager',
            'entity'   => 'doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager'
        ];

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface $container
     * @param array              $managers
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, array $managers = array())
    {
        $this->container = $container;
        parent::__construct($managers);
    }

    /**
     * @param $type
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function getManager($type)
    {
        return $this->container->get($this->managers[$type]);
    }
}
```

Listener defination

```
acme.listener.reference:
       class: ACME\CoreBundle\Listener\ReferencesListener
       arguments: ["@service_container"]
       tags:
           - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using doctrine extension's references you need to make sure you have registered [the subscriber](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/References/ReferencesListener.php) with doctrine. Otherwise the references won't work.

In symfony2 you can [register](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html) doctrine listeners/subscribers using container tags:

**config.yml**

```
services:
    gedmo_reference_listener:          # choose whatever name you like
        class: Gedmo\References\ReferencesListener
        arguments: 
            - { entity: @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, document: @doctrine.odm.mongodb.document_manager }
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
```

This is what StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle usually does in the bundle's [compilerpass](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L69). It just simplifies the process of registering the services using a bit of configuration.

But as you can see [here](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L69) ... @stof didn't yet add the reference listener to the configuration options.

There is already an open [pull request](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/pull/192) but @stof doesn't want to add it until the implementation has been refactored. Meanwhile use my solution above :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Your solution is not working cause it seems that i need to pass an index through the service container. Do you have any idea?

Notice: Undefined index: document in       /vagrant/www/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/References/ReferencesListener.php line 122

Comment: updated my answer you have to inject an array of object-managers ( entity-manager, document-manager, ... ) into the constructor of the listener

Comment: just ran into another exception: ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", path: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> gedmo_reference_listener".

i quiet new to symfony but i beginn to  understand the fundermentals of the container

Comment: for me it seems like i try to inject a class which needs another object for which the instance is needed.. so i end in a loop

Comment: looks like the managers passed to the constructor has to be an associative array "type" -> manager ... https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/References/ReferencesListener.php#L120 ... maybe we need a service factory here ... investigating

Comment: okay seems like we need an array { document: `@document_manager` , entity: `@entity_manager` } ... the original error thrown at line 122 indicates that type can be 'document'. updated my answer. does it work now or circular reference again?

Comment: yes.. i end up into another circular reference

ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", path: "http_kernel -> debug.event_dispatcher -> profiler -> security.context -> security.authentication.manager -> fos_user.user_provider.username -> fos_user.user_manager -> doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> gedmo_reference_listener".

Comment: trying  to solve the puzzle using a callable ... updating when i found success

Comment: had you had time to dig into it?

Comment: Didn't forget you, but i have to work today and i'll come back to you afterwards okay? :)

Comment: ah there was something - I'm back in the game ... :D There seems to be a working example in PR https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/pull/625/files by OpenSky. Did you already have a look at that one?

Comment: It would be nice to post the important parts of the PR code into this question and accept it as an answer @nifr . Thanks in advance!

Comment: @webDEVILopers: I haven't asked this question ...  so I can't accept an answer. Yet my answer solves the issue. Feel free to propose an edit including the parts of the PR that you think might help others in the future.

Comment: Sorry, missed the original author @nifr. Unfortunately the PR at https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/issues/625 is gone. I am trying to create a working example with the SonataAdminBundle and see if the solution relates to this question.

Comment: I tried your solution @nifr but ran into the same error as user2485214 did and mentioned above: ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager", path: "doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> gedmo_reference_listener". Too bad the PR with the obvious solution is gone. Am I still missing something to make your solution work?

Comment: I think the issue is also discussed here: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/821

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try from :

```
services:
    # reference behavior doctrine < mongodb
    gedmo.listener.reference:
        class: Gedmo\References\ReferencesListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_subscriber }
        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]
            - [ registerManager, [ 'entity', "@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager" ] ]

    # reference behavior doctrine > mongodb
    gedmo.listener.reference:
        class: Gedmo\References\ReferencesListener
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }

        calls:
            - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]
            - [ registerManager, [ 'document', "@doctrine_mongodb.odm.document_manager" ] ]
```

They both work for me, but alone...

If you put them both like this only the second is taken

Comment: You're actively overwriting the first service by providing the SAME service-name (`gedmo.listener.reference`) with both subscribers. Change one of the service's names and both subscribers will be active.

Comment: When trying to set individual service names like gedmo.listener.reference_one and ..reference_two I get this error: ServiceCircularReferenceException: Circular reference detected for service "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager", path: "doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_document_manager -> doctrine_mongodb.odm.default_connection -> doctrine_mongodb.odm.event_manager -> gedmo.listener.reference_orm -> doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager -> doctrine.dbal.default_connection -> gedmo.listener.reference_odm".